# SharePoint Online- Remove-PnpFile question

Tags: pnp-powershell

I have a script that is working to download files from an online SharePoint Document Library to a network drive. Now I just need to be able to delete the files that have already been downloaded from the SharePoint document library. I know I need each files site url but am unsure of how to collect it and then use remove-pnpfile. Here is my script:

```
#################### Parameters ###########################################
$webUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/teams/CPRPlusPST"
$listUrl = "Documents";
$destination = "\\cpr-appsprod\cprsql\Incoming"
$Username = "***"
$Password = "***"


#region Credentials 
[securestring]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username,$SecurePass)
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl -Credentials $PSCredentials
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$list = Get-PNPList -Identity $listUrl

function ProcessFolder ($folderUrl,$destinationFolder) {

  $folder = Get-PnPFolder -RelativeUrl $folderUrl
  $tempfiles = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property Files

  if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationfolder)) {
    $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -Type directory
  }

  $total = $folder.Files.Count
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $total; $i++) {
    $file = $folder.Files[$i]

    Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $file.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $destinationfolder -FileName $file.Name -AsFile -Force
    Write-Host -f Green "Downloaded File:" $file.Name

    ***Remove-PnPFile  -Force
    Write-Host -f Green "Deleted File from SharePoint:" $file.Name***
  }
}

function ProcessSubFolders ($folders,$currentPath) {
  foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $file = $folder.Files
    $tempurls = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property ServerRelativeUrl
    #'Signed tickets' folder only
    if ($folder.Name -eq "Signed tickets") {
      $targetFolder = $currentPath + "\";
      ProcessFolder $folder.ServerRelativeUrl.Substring($web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length) $targetFolder
      $tempfolders = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property Folders
      ProcessSubFolders $tempfolders $targetFolder
    }
  }
}

#Download root files
#ProcessFolder $listUrl $destination + "\" 
#Download files in folders
$tempfolders = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $list.RootFolder -Property Folders
ProcessSubFolders $tempfolders $destination + "\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<Domain-Name>.sharepoint.com/sites/adidas *#I’m Prompted for Credentials*

$items = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "test/folder/folder1" -ItemType File
foreach ($Item in $Items)
{
   $Name = $item.Name
   Remove-PNPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/adidas/test/folder/folder1/$Name" -Force *#File’s are deleted permanently and won’t be moved to recycle bin.*
}
```

Hope this helps you.